# Сould not dequeue a view of kind

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

error: could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier currencyCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

I don’t understand what the mistake is. In the storyboard, both collectionViews have ReuseIdentifier

What else is needed?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource  {
  // MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet var currencyCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var categoryCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    let category = ["Popular", "Sports", "Insider", "Auto", "Science"]
    
  // MARK: Private properties
    private var currencyList: [Currency] = []
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == categoryCollectionView {
            return category.count
        }
        return currencyList.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "currencyCell", for: indexPath) as! CurrencyCollectionViewCell
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.label.text = currencyList[indexPath.row].name
        cell.value.text = currencyList[indexPath.row].value
        
        if collectionView == categoryCollectionView {
            let categoryCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "categoryCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
            categoryCell.categoryLabel.text = category[indexPath.row]
            categoryCell.backgroundColor = .blue
            return categoryCell
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: outlets are connected?

Comment: Yes, in CollectionViewCell

Comment: i meant the collection view itself

Answer (score 0):

[image: Set Collectionview cell identifier]

If you're using cell of cellectionview itself the you need to provide cell identifier as shown in screenshot and it must be same in code also as show below

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AppListCell", for: indexPath) as! CurrencyCollectionViewCell
```

Comment: I wrote that everything is indicated in the storyboard.